# Calibrating the current (uA) of a TI by using a 34465A DMM as a std and a suitable load

Tags: current, measurement, uncertainty

When calibrating a test instrument (TI) on its current generation using the DMM 34465A as the standard and a suitable load in series, I think the uncertainty budget should not include the accuracy and the certificate uncertainty of the resistive load. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the load is only used to pull some current "X".  Then the test instrument is calibrated to the reference DMM reading.

So the absolute value of X isn't important, as long as it's within an acceptable range determined by the calibration requirements.

Therefore I would agree that the accuracy and uncertainty of the load isn't a factor.

Comment: Many thanks John